# What to do if the accepted answer is not the best?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows) I came across, the accepted answer is a good answer.  However, a later answer (later by only 2 hours) is a better answer to the question.

Is there a way to change the accepted answer? (Note, not my question)  Or should I just vote the most correct answer up?

Comment: If you mouseover the check mark, you'll see that *"The question owner accepted this as the best answer"*. Unless you're the *question owner*, there's nothing you can do about it. Just something you need to know about the checkmarks, they can seem to be assigned arbitrary and even to answers not actually answering the stated question...

Answer (score 5):

No one but the original poster can change the accepted answer, <strike>remember that answers get ordered by votes(by default) so an answer with more votes will be displayed first</strike>

Actually, when sorting by votes, accepted answers go first, then the rest in descending score order (with random order when two answers have the same score). [Example](https://superuser.com/questions/375690/how-can-i-use-two-parameters-at-once-with-xargs)

Thanks to DB for the clarification.

Comment: I figured I couldn't actually change the answer, but perhaps a way to influence the answer other than voting.  Guess not :o

Comment: Commenting to why the other answer is 'better' is good too

Comment: Actually, when sorting by *votes*, accepted answers go first, then the rest in descending score order (with random order when two answers have the same score). [Example](http://superuser.com/questions/375690/how-can-i-use-two-parameters-at-once-with-xargs).

Comment: ...unless the Accepted answer author is also the Question author.

Comment: Well that seems like strange behaviour.  I would have assumed that sorting answers **by votes** would put **the highest voted answer first**, no?   *Regardless* of whom wrote the answer, I think that this behaviour should possibly be changed (i.e. put highest voted answer first, then accepted answer, then remaining highest voted answers).